# XCode + Bitbucket - Create new remote

Tags: ios, xcode, bitbucket

I've been looking for a solution with *Bitbucket* and *XCode*. But I only have found how to add remote. How can I create new remote using *XCode*?
I have tried to add server *bitbucket.org* and than I tried to fill user name and password, but I had an error.

> Unable to perform the request. CFNetwork error: Could not connect to
>   the server. (-1004 - kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost)

Comment: I don't how your question relates to creating the remote repo on Bitbucket; it seems to be more about authentication, which is something that will affect the whole git lifecycle.

Comment: I tried create repo using XCode, but something is going wrong.

Comment: You cannot create a remote repo on Xcode or anywhere else on your client machine other than the web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a remote repo on Xcode or anywhere else on your client machine other than the web browser. – Droppy